# Return exact number of days in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, case

Need help on below query

When I have run the below query

```
select case when CAST(var1 as DATE) >= CAST(getdate() as DATE) -5 then 1 else 0 end as temp

---where "var1" is datetime variable
```

I see error - Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int.

Please help

Comment: `CAST(getdate() as DATE) -5` Error. you can't `datetime - int`

Comment: You're subtracting `int` from `datetime`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `DATEADD`.

```
DECLARE @var1 datetime = '2019-12-31 00:00:00'

select case when CAST(@var1 as DATE) >= DATEADD(day,-5,CAST(getdate() as DATE)) then 1 else 0 end as temp
```

The DATEADD() function adds/remove a time/date interval to a date and then returns the date.

Syntax:

```
DATEADD(interval, number, date)
```

[Here is the tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to function to add a specified value to a specified date part of a date.
you can use `DATEADD`.

syntax of the `DATEADD()`:

```
DATEADD (date_part , value , input_date )
```

e.g

```
DATEADD(second, 1, GETDATE())
DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE())
DATEADD(month, 4, GETDATE())
```

then:

```
DECLARE @var1 DATETIME = '2019-10-20'

SELECT CASE 
        WHEN CAST(@var1 AS DATE) >= DATEADD(MONTH, 4, GETDATE()) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
   END AS temp
```